# T-SQL Probe residual

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance-testing

I am testing probe residual, joining tables with mismatching datatypes to see how that hurts performance. In this test, I join two tables, once with mismatching datatypes (nvarchar versus varchar) and once with matching datatypes. The code I used:

```
SELECT REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID()), '-', '') AS ColA,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ( SELECT 1)) AS RowNumb
INTO #Varchar
FROM sys.all_objects AS S
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS S2

SELECT CAST (ColA AS NVARCHAR (255)) AS ColA,
       RowNumb
INTO #Nvarchar
FROM #Varchar

SELECT TOP 1000000 *
INTO #Subset
FROM #Varchar

CREATE INDEX i_VarcharColA ON #Varchar (ColA)
CREATE INDEX i_NvarcharColA ON #Nvarchar (ColA)
CREATE INDEX i_SubsetColA ON #Subset (ColA)

SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountStar
FROM #Varchar AS V
INNER JOIN #Subset AS S ON V.ColA = S.ColA -- matching datatypes

SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountStar
FROM #Nvarchar AS V
INNER JOIN #Subset AS S ON V.ColA = S.ColA -- non-matching datatypes
```

There is a big difference in performance. To my absolute surprise however, using the mismatching datatypes actually performs way better.

I must be overlooking something, but any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: matching datatypes - get NL join, non-matching datatypes - HASH. yes hash more fast, but more resources server, of course this assumption, compare the execution plans

Comment: did something get cached?  HAVE A google for clearing buffers and plans for SQL performance testing - sorry I haven't got the info to hand - but does the execution of your first query 'help' the second one?  You could also swap them round

Comment: @Cato switching them did not make any difference. Stil the 'wrong' query does way better.

Comment: @TapakahUa So when your main goal is to reduce runtime, in some cases intentionally setting mismatching datatypes is actually better. Interesting, I think that's pretty counter-intuitive.

Comment: On my machine (SQL Server 2017), with all data resident in memory, the "matching datatypes" query is about twice as fast under parallelism and 1.3 times as fast under `MAXDOP 1`. Of course, the execution plans for these queries are quite different, so their actual execution time will depend on your exact configuration (and version of SQL Server). That said, under `MAXDOP 1` the second query is just the first with an extra conversion step inserted, so it would be very strange indeed to see that perform better.

Comment: i get matching taking more CPU, but less time elapsed

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your input. Ran it on another server (other SQL version) and got about 50-50 results. As is often the case in SQL, nothing is clear cut, it all depends.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add OPTION (RECOMPILE, MAXDOP 1) for clear test
2. Test with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS (remove all buffers from the buffer pool)
3. In my sql (2016) first query "faster"
4. test without MAXDOP = 1:

> ```
>  INNER JOIN matching type -> NL JOIN
>  CPU time = 15251 ms,  elapsed time = 4848 ms.
>
>  INNER JOIN non-matching type -> MERGE JOIN + SORT 
>  CPU time = 15889 ms,  elapsed time = 9776 ms.
> ```

5. test with MAXDOP = 1

> ```
> INNER JOIN matching type -> NL JOIN    
> CPU time = 8438 ms,  elapsed time = 9307 ms.
>
> INNER JOIN non-matching type -> NL JOIN + sort    
> CPU time = 8687 ms,  elapsed time = 10130 ms.
> ```

Earlier versions may have a different plan, I so expect that non-matching type get HASH JOIN and more CPU.

p/s Sql server tries to create a cheaper plan, saving resources at the expense of speed of execution

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I cannot seem to replicate the results, in all my tests the mismatching is slightly better or way better. Still, good explanation, thanks.